# How do I add a class to a form in ruby on rails without setting / overriding the existing default helper class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, form-for

Adding a class for `form_for` through the `html: {class: "form-horizontal"}` option overrides the default `new_model` or `edit_model` class. How do I add my class while keeping the existing form_helper class?

I want:

`<form class="edit_model form-horizontal">` or

`<form class="new_model form-horizontal">`

Instead of:

`<form class="form-horizontal">`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into exactly the same issue. Eventually, I came up with this solution

```
form_for @foo, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal #{controller.action_name}_model_name"}
```

It might be a little too late for this to be of much use to you, but maybe someone else will find it useful.

Comment: This method doesn't always work / can yield a different result in some cases. For example when I did this for my Devise signup form that's embedded on my homepage, it changed from new_user to index_user.

Answer (score 4):

Defining classes via the `:html => {:class => '...'}` option overrides any classes added by the default builder.   However, you can append CSS classes within the block without overriding those classes.

With the `form_for` helper, the `:class` will be a string if not otherwise set.  Note the leading space when appending.  (**Update**:  also note that the string will be *frozen* in recent versions of Rails, so `+=` must be used instead of `<<` to avoid a "can't modify frozen String" error.)

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
  <% f.options[:html][:class] += ' form-horizontal' %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>

<form class="edit_model form-horizontal">
```

If you're using the `simple_form_for` helper, `options[:html][:class]` will be an array, and you don't need the extra leading space (although it doesn't hurt).

```
<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>
  <% f.options[:html][:class] << 'form-horizontal' %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>

<form class="simple_form edit_model form-horizontal">
```

If you're using a symbol instead of a model, `form_for` will not set the class, and `options[:html][:class]` will be `nil` in the block.  But if you're doing this you don't have a model to be new or persisted anyway.

```
<%= form_for :model do |f| %>
  <% f.options[:html][:class] << ' form-horizontal' %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>

NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an ideal solution, but have you considered doing it with JS/Jquery?

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.edit_model').addClass('form-horizontal')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the view helper `dom_class(object, prefix = nil)` to generate class names like `form_for` does.

It's not very clean doing it directly in the form, but incorporating it into a helper might be just the ticket.  For example:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def class_for object, *additional_classes
  additional_classes.unshift dom_class(object, object.persisted? ? 'edit' : 'new')
end

# app/views/models/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @model, :html => {:class => class_for(@model, 'form-horizontal')} do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>

<form class="new_model form-horizontal" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html: {class: "edit_model form-horizontal"}
```

Comment: The beauty of the form builder is that it automatically switches between the edit_model and new_model classes. I would like an elegant way to do this without having to put the object inside of an if statement that detects whether or not it's a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the merge method? [http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge] Something like html = html.merge(new) { |key, value1, value2| value1 + " " + value2 } would let you feed the new value into the class value. [Quick edit: Be careful to configure and test the implementation so you don't completely overwrite html)